# mysql table join problem

Tags: mysql, sql

#### table: user

```
id     name
-------------
1      john
2      paul
3      mattew
```

#### table: nickname

```
id    user_id    nickname
--------------------------
1     1          frog
2     1          cow
3     1          bull
4     2          cat
```

Result I want:

```
 1     john     frog cow bull
 2     paul     cat
 3     mattew
```

How can I get this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, GROUP_CONCAT(n.nickname, ' ') AS nickname
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN nickname n ON u.id = n.user_id
GROUP BY u.id, u.name
```

Please Note: syntax for GROUP_CONCAT may not be perfect because I haven't used it in a while

Answer (score 2):

Use mysql aggregate functions: Group concat will do the trick for you.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat